# Pandas Groupby Sum to Columns

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I am doing groupby and can get the sum for a column ok, but how to I get sum of two columns together?

```
detail [ 'debit' ] = df.groupby ( 'type' ) [ 'debit' ].sum ()
detail [ 'credit' ] = df.groupby ( 'type' ) [ 'credit' ].sum ()
```

Now I need the (credit - debit) together.

something like this:

```
detail [ 'profit' ] = df.groupby ( 'type' ) ( [ 'credit' ] - [ 'debit'  ] ).sum ()
```

obviously that does not work.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean this `df.groupby ( 'type' ) ( [ 'credit' , 'debit'] ).sum ()`

Comment: Why not `detail [ 'profit' ] = detail [ 'credit' ] - detail [ 'debit' ]`?

Comment: @IanS and apply the groupby afterwards (just fpr completeness)

Comment: @EyJay good idea, you should make it an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @IanS suggested, I would first save the result in a new column and apply the groupby function afterwards:

```
df['profit'] = df['credit'] - df['debit']
detail = df.groupby('type').sum()[['profit', 'credit', 'debit']]
```

I also combined the the groupby-actions into one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

`detail [ 'profit' ] = sum(df.groupby ( 'type' ) [ 'credit' ] - df.groupby ( 'type' ) [ 'debit' ])`